# Matrix generation based on list's objects in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, apply, matrix-multiplication

I have a list of objects in `R` like follows:

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- matrix(rnorm(3*4,mean=0,sd=1), 3, 4) 
results <- lapply(1:ncol(data), function(i) outer(data[, i], data[, i]))
```

which will result in the following matrices

```
[[1]]
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.4570077 -0.33487534 -1.3089918
[2,] -0.3348753  0.07696698  0.3008557
[3,] -1.3089918  0.30085569  1.1760127

[[2]]
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  5.502298 -1.0065968 -1.1870541
[2,] -1.006597  0.1841480  0.2171611
[3,] -1.187054  0.2171611  0.2560926

[[3]]
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.3303260 0.3141712 0.3244131
[2,] 0.3141712 0.2988064 0.3085474
[3,] 0.3244131 0.3085474 0.3186061

[[4]]
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.7921673 0.4247196 0.8886017
[2,] 0.4247196 0.2277129 0.4764227
[3,] 0.8886017 0.4764227 0.9967755
```

How can I create a single matrix containing the Interquartile Range (*IQR*) between the corresponding elements? Meaning the new matrix will be a B=`3X3` matrix with for example `B(1,1)=IQR(c(1.4570077,5.502298,0.3303260,0.7921673))=1.791623`, `B(1,2)=IQR(c(-0.33487534, -1.0065968, 0.3141712, 0.4247196))= 0.844614`. How can I use the `apply` function to create this new matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may convert the `list` to `array` and then use `apply` with `MARGIN` as `c(1, 2)` and apply the `IQR` elementwise

```
apply(simplify2array(results), c(1, 2), IQR)
```

-output

```
      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 1.791623 0.84461397 1.68299882
[2,] 0.844614 0.08813351 0.07058422
[3,] 1.682999 0.07058422 0.73860710
```

---

Or another option is `transpose` the `list` and then apply the `IQR` by looping over the `list`

```
library(purrr)
`dim<-`(map_dbl(transpose(results), IQR), dim(results[[1]]))
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 1.791623 0.84461397 1.68299882
[2,] 0.844614 0.08813351 0.07058422
[3,] 1.682999 0.07058422 0.73860710
```